# Is there a list of Kafka log4j appenders?

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j

Is there a list of the log files/appenders that I can configure to enable for kafka/zookeeper?  I can see in the log4j.properties file there are some different appenders defined:

```
log4j.appender.kafkaAppender
log4j.appender.statechangeAppender
log4j.appender.requestAppender
etc.
```

Is there a listing someplace of the logs/appenders that can be created and managed for Kafka/Zookeeper?